# Kendo UI Mobile, datasource driven ListView is narrowing on each show

Tags: css, listview, kendo-mobile

I have a listview in my applications in which the data comes from the datasource.

My problem is, the width of the listview is getting smaller on each showing the view which includes the listview. I checked my oter istviews also and saw that some have the same problem.

Comment: You need to show your code otherwise it is difficult to help you. My guess is that you are doing `.kendoMobileListView()` in a `show` event of the view instead of just once on `init`. View's DOM elements are retained even when you leave the view, so you don't need to re-create them each time.

Comment: Yes, the mistake was as you mentioned calling .kendoMobileListView each time. thank you